# login php not working

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I've this set of login codes. When I type the correct password, I'll be able to get into the webpage. But I'm not sure why, when I type the wrong password, I will still be able to get into the webpage.

I am not sure where is the error.

This is my php code:

```
<?php

//define page title
$title = 'Sign In';

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

  $UserEmail = isset($_GET['UserEmail']) ? $_GET['UserEmail'] : '';

  $Password = isset($_GET['Password']) ? $_GET['Password'] : '';


 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE UserEmail='$UserEmail'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['Password']=md5($Password))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['Password'];
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
     <?php
     }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: it's okay, i have figured it out already!

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking user password, that is why it will allow you to access page with wrong credentials.

Try this,

```html
<?php

//define page title
$title = 'Sign In';

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{

  $UserEmail = isset($_GET['UserEmail']) ? $_GET['UserEmail'] : '';

  $Password = isset($_GET['Password']) ? $_GET['Password'] : '';


 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE UserEmail='$UserEmail' and password='$Password'");
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 if($row['Password']=md5($Password))
 {
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['Password'];
  header("Location: home.php");
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
     <?php
     }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Destroy session and check again

Comment: @Celine.Tan have you checked ?

Comment: what do you mean by destroy session and check again? sorry cause i am new at this

Answer (score 0):

You are posting form then you would get variables in `$_POST` not `$_GET`.

```
$UserEmail = isset($_POST['UserEmail']) ? $_POST['UserEmail'] : '';

$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';
```

Comment: Did you print your query and run it in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your query with below:

```
<?php
//define page title
$title = 'Sign In';
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
    $UserEmail = isset($_GET['UserEmail']) ? $_GET['UserEmail'] : '';
    $Password = isset($_GET['Password']) ? $_GET['Password'] : '';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE UserEmail='$UserEmail' AND Password='" . md5($Password) . "'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (count($row) > 0) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['Password'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help! :) but now when i enter the wrong password, i will have an error "Undefined variable: res". how do i stop it from prompting me this error?

Comment: there is this syntax error and now i am not able to login at all even with the correct pasword or user

Comment: @Celine.Tan Not like that, on which line of my given code. Because i dont have your full code.

Comment: it's okay, i have this new error now "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in"

Comment: @Celine.Tan Can you please check i updated my answer with your and my full code. Check it and let me know.

Comment: now even with the correct useremail and password, i am not able to go in to "home.php"

Comment: @Celine.Tan Can you `print_r($row);` after `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed wrong is

`if($row['Password']=md5($Password))`

Use '==' (double equal) for equality check. Single equal is assignment

`if($row['Password']==md5($Password))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
```

that one is senseless too. I'm almost sure that it will always pass because "false"!=""

So change it to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user']))
```